# Open file with correct program, in terminal, based on extension

Tags: command-line, file-format

Is there any way to automatically open a file with the correct program, when using the terminal? Something similar with double clicking a file in GUI.

So for example having a pdf file, not need to write

```
evince foo.pdf
```

in order to open it.

Comment: `xdg-open foo.pdf`

Comment: @kenn [^this^](http://askubuntu.com/questions/549289/open-file-with-correct-program-in-terminal-based-on-extension#comment752514_549289) is the answer. Why not you post it as an answer?